# What are the barriers to partial nonrocket spacelaunch?

Tags: launch

What technological and financial barriers prevent proposals for partial nonrocket spacelaunch such as magnetic levitation trains from becoming a reality?  These systems, if created, could substantially reduce the delta-v required by rockets to achieve orbit.

I would exclude space elevators from this discussion, as those have already been discussed at length elsewhere.

Comment: I feel like this paper covered it pretty well: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijae/2012/830536/ it might help someone trying to write an answer.

Comment: Could you perhaps specify a specific technology you're interested in? As it stands this question is too broad.

Comment: Since the space elevator is already discussed, maglev or gun systems seem (to me) to be the most realistic proposals.